# AIX auditpr timestamp format

Tags: aix, timestamps, audit

Is there a way to customize the timestamp format that the auditpr command on AIX generates?

I am logging to binary, and when I use auditpr to read the binary audit logs, I get something similar to :

```
event           login    status      time                     command                         wpar name                 long login
--------------- -------- ----------- ------------------------ ------------------------------- ------------------------- ----------
AUD_LOG_READ    root     OK          Thu Sep 27 19:46:17 2018 rsyslogd                        Global                    root
```

I have a script that parses this from multiple servers, and there are 2 issues with that time format:

1. Hard for a script to parse with default time parsing utilities.
2. It doesn't include the UTC offset to compare logs from server in different time zones.

I'd prefer:

```
event           login    status      time                       command                         wpar name                 long login
--------------- -------- ----------- -------------------------- ------------------------------- ------------------------- ----------
AUD_LOG_READ    root     OK          2018-09-27T19:46:17+00:00  rsyslogd                        Global                    root
```

Does AIX provide the means to output the timestamp in the requested format, or another format that includes the UTC offset?